# Why is content_tag helper printing the "flash" contents in the browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view-helpers

To explain further, I have the following code in my Rails app Layout:

```
<!-- Stuff omitted -->
<% unless flash.empty? %>
  <%= flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<%= yield %>
```

And for the controller:

```
#stuff omitted
def create
  user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
  if user
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
  else
    flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
    render :new
  end
end
```

Ok, so, If I happen to fail the authentication, this is what I'm seeing in the browser:

[image: content_tag error?]

Can you guys tell me why is the hash({:alert => "Invalid email or password"}) appearing under the message? I'm really clueless about what is wrong,

(BTW, This is taken from Rails Casts #250)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the equal sign from the start of the loop:

```
<!-- Stuff omitted -->
<% unless flash.empty? %>
  <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<%= yield %>
```

Because it tells ERB to print entire `flash` variable.

Comment: Yes, I can't believe I didn't see this one. I'm sorry, this is so embarrassing. Anyways, Thank you very much for your time !

Answer (score 1):

It looks like message ends up being a hash. Try setting the flash message like this:

```
flash[:alert] = "Invalid email or password"
```

Comment: Sorry, the result is the same. I just don't get it, the hash is being printed outside the div created by content_tag. I don't know why.

Comment: Do you have an errant debug statement somewhere? Like a to_yaml call? a <%= debug flash %> for a <%= y flash %> ?

Comment: negative sir, I don't. The app is very small(given it just follows a rails cast)

Comment: I've got it! this is so embarrasing.. the problem is the equals in this expression: <%= flash.each do |name, msg| %>

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

- in `application.html.erb` you can write:

  ```
  <% unless flash.empty? %>
    <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
      <%= content_tag :div, msg, class: "alert alert-#{name}" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= yield %>
  ```
- in controller you can write:

  `flash[:danger] = "Invalid email or password"`